# Map View dismiss MKAnnotationView after setCenter - MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm trying to center my `mapView` with my `MKAnnotation` while displaying `MKAnnotationView`. However, when I call `mapView.setCenter`, my annotation is dismissed. I've tried a `delay` and `mapView.selectAnnotation` but that didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {return}
    if view.annotation is FBAnnotationCluster {return}

    if let annotation = view.annotation as? PinAnnotation {
        ProfessionalDetailView.showViewWith(annotation.professional, and: self)
        var center = annotation.coordinate;
        center.latitude -= self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 8
        mapView.setCenter(center, animated: true)
        delay(1, closure: {
            mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
        })   
    }
}
```

Comment: How about do not selecting annotation? Dose everything work fine?

Comment: I didn't get, you mean not touch annotation?

Comment: YES ..............

Comment: Well.. then it will do what supposed to do..  I'll add more context to the question...